# .htaccess file not working properly in ionos. My website- https://rentocure.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ionos

I want to have clean link like- [https://rentocure.com/doctors/rc635502e5e9376](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) instead of [https://rentocure.com/doctors.php?uid=rc635502e5e9376](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) (U can go through my website). I have the following code in localhost

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?home/([^/]+)?$ "index.php" [L,QSA]
ErrorDocument 404 https://rentocure.com/404/
RewriteRule ^doctors/([^/]*)$ doctors.php?uid=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^hospitals/([^/]*)$ hospitals.php?uid=$1 [L]
```

which is working fine in localhost but not in ionos apache server so I changed it to the following:

```
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Redirect to SSL Secured Page
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://rentocure.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Removing File Extension .php and adding trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

#Custom 404 Page
ErrorDocument 404 https://rentocure.com/404/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^doctors/([^/]*)$ doctors/?uid=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But still it is not working kindly check my website and give me the solution. For the one whose solution will work for me will get assured cash reward from me.

Expecting solution through .htaccess code.

Comment: So you are hitting link `https://rentocure.com/doctors.php?uid=rc635502e5e9376` and you want it to redirect to `https://rentocure.com/doctors/rc635502e5e9376` in browser?

Comment: I want to rewrite my link like this https://rentocure.com/doctors/rc635502e5e9376 instead of https://rentocure.com/doctors.php?uid=rc635502e5e9376